# How to Convert sql server query to linq in entity framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am converting the `sql server` query to `linq`

```
 SELECT * FROM DataFlow where FlowDeleted = 0 and 
    DataFlow.FlowVersionNumber = 
    (
    SELECT MAX(FlowVersionNumber) from DataFlow i
    where FlowDeleted = 0 AND
    i.FlowCounter = DataFlow.FlowCounter
    group by FlowCounter
    )
    ORDER by 1
```

My Linq query Code is:

```
     public List<DataFlow> getdataflow() 
    var dflow = db.DataFlows.Where (
        d => d.FlowDeleted == false &&

        d.FlowVersionNumber =
        (
            db.DataFlows.Where(i => i.FlowDeleted == false && i.FlowCounter == d.FlowCounter).GroupBy(g => g.FlowCounter)
                .Select(s => s.Max(m => m.FlowVersionNumber))
        )
    )

.Select(s =>
    new DataFlow
    {
        FlowCounter = s.FlowCounter,
        FlowDescription = s.FlowDescription,
        FlowName = s.FlowName,
    }).OrderBy(o => o.FlowCounter);

    return dflow.ToList();
}
```

But it giving error like: `Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' ... 'string'"`

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You are using assignment operator instead of comparing... try `..d.FlowVersionNumber ==...`

```
db.DataFlows.Where(d => 
    d.FlowDeleted == false &&
    d.FlowVersionNumber == db.DataFlows.Where(i => 
        i.FlowDeleted == false && 
        i.FlowCounter == d.FlowCounter).GroupBy(g => g.FlowCounter)
                                       .First(s => s.Max(m => m.FlowVersionNumber))
    )
)
```

I changed `Select` to `First` because you need to compare scalars. However, be sure that you WILL find an item, or you could get an exception.